# mysql search LIKE not working for long phrase

Tags: mysql, database

I have a MySQL table, type 'MyISAM', collation: 'latin1_swedish_ci'. Inside it, I have a column named 'content'.

Inside there, I have a row with the following content:

```
<p>The state will have a different advantage over most other states, with one of the largest populations in the nation to blablablabla. </p>
```

My query is this in phpMyAdmin and also in my PHP file:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pages`
WHERE `content` LIKE '%with one of the largest populations%'
ORDER BY `pages`.`title` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

0 rows are returned.

The weird thing is that if I edit the query to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pages`
WHERE `content` LIKE '%with one of the largest%'
ORDER BY `pages`.`title` ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Then , 1 rows are returned, and it works.

Is there any setting that might limit the search query to only a few words or only a few characters?

Comment: most probably there are any other whitespace character(s), otherwise, your query seems fine

Comment: Agree with @RabNawaz; can you paste output of `SELECT HEX(content) WHERE content LIKE '%with one of the largest%'`?

Comment: I know the query is fine and it is weird. The only thing that crosses my mind is that it has something to do with the collation type or with the table type. Maybe there is a limit or smth.

Comment: no, try this `largest populations` should also return 0 recs

Comment: Both are working fine check here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa511/8

Comment: @RabNawaz , if I try '%largest populations%', it returns 0 rows, yes.

Comment: I just copy pasted the entire text of that row for column 'content'

Comment: Found the problem. There was a different code for space, something copy pasted from MS Word, which was not threated as a space, between the words largest and population.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably there are any other whitespace character(s), otherwise, your query seems fine.

try this `largest populations` should also return 0 recs.

So replace, those characters from column before, searching.

[You can find some help here](https://www.google.com/search?q=remove%20white%20space%20characters%20mysql&aq=f&oq=remove%20white%20space%20characters%20mysql&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=remove%20special%20invisible%20characters%20mysql&oq=remove%20special%20invisible%20characters%20mysql&gs_l=serp.3...211754.214750.1.216179.8.8.0.0.0.6.568.4369.5-8.8.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.XQHsd20s9Y4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44442042,d.bGE&fp=2582cfa7b828ddbd&biw=1280&bih=899)